# LVL Licensing in Honeycomb Emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-lvl

I'm currently only using the Honeycomb emulator to test a new Fragment-based release, which requires the LVL licensing service. However, every time I start my app on the emulator, it fails the licensing test and my emulator cannot add Google accounts, so I can't try that way either.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that nobody has been able to get the LVL libraries working on any emulator except 2.2. See [this posting](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/30e7724bf6aae46c/66f5eac0c594be99?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=lvl%20emulator%203.0#66f5eac0c594be99) and [this issue report](http://code.google.com/p/marketlicensing/issues/detail?id=27&q=could%20not%20bind%20to%20service).

Comment: Soo... Google are asking us to use their new shiny licensing service, and then not support it on their emulators? Hmm... thanks for the response though :)

Comment: It seems that way. I think it's...disappointing. (I was going to use another word.)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issues with LVL... however to create the google account on your emulator make sure you create it with the google libraries.. IF you create the emulator with the google libraries you will get the google account set up when you create accounts.